# What app is this notification for?

Tags: samsung, notification-bar, notification-icons

[image]1. List item

What app does this notification icon belong to? It was sent to me in a screenshot from a Samsung Galaxy s22

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Sorry, since there are millions of Android apps and more for notification icons, [the community can't help anymore in identifying a specific icon of an app](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2435/44325).